# How to send google Appscript Error logs to slack

Tags: google-apps-script, error-logging

I have different appscript projects which have triggers to run every hour.
I would like appscript to be sending the error logs to slack instead of email.
Any idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using a `try ... catch` on your code that calls [the Slack API](https://api.slack.com/start) when it catches an exception.

Another (more complex) way would be by monitoring the logs using the [Google Cloud Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest) or the [Google Cloud Error Reporting API](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest).